# Each function triggers only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, owl-carousel

I'm trying to triggers a function on several owl-carousel sliders having the same class. If i do a console.log, it logs twice, but works only on the first slider.

Here's my function:

```
function setActiveItem(){
        var item = $('.owl-item');
        var itemLink = $('.owl-item a');
        var pos = $('.is-active').parent().parent().index();

        $('.slider-mobile').each(function() {
            if($(this).find(itemLink).is('.is-active')) {
                item.removeClass('active');
                $(this).trigger('to.owl.carousel', [pos, 1, true]);
            }
        })
    }

    setActiveItem();
```

And here's a simplified version of my markup:

```
<ul class="list-container slider-mobile" data-stage-padding-items="200">
    <li class="list-item">
        <a href="#" class="title title--small list-link is-active">item</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="slider-mobile" data-stage-padding-items="200">
    <li class="list-item">
        <a href="#" class="title title--small list-link is-active">item</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm not sure if i'm using the each() function right, or if it fits my need at all.

Comment: your simplified version of the HTML does not contain all the elements that are referenced in the javascript. Hard to tell what you are trying to achieve here then...

Comment: Have you tried putting the selector `.owl-item a` inside the find() method instead of a reference to `itemLink`? My guess is that you are always referencing the same item so find will only be true in certain situations

Comment: Just tried, doesn't work but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i figured it out.
@Reinder Wit you were right i was referencing the item of the first slider only, so both of my sliders were getting the same datas.

I did this:

```
function setActiveItem(){

        $('.slider-mobile').each(function() {
            var item = $(this).find('.owl-item');
            var itemLink = $(this).find('.owl-item a');
            var pos = $(this).find('.is-active').parent().parent().index();

            if($(this).find(itemLink).is('.is-active')) {
                item.removeClass('active');
                $(this).trigger('to.owl.carousel', [pos, 1, true]);
                console.log(pos);
            }
        })
    }

    setActiveItem();
```

And it is working now. Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 0):

You should activate your listener in the document ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setActiveItem();
});
```

Comment: It is i just didn't typed it here :)

Comment: I think you need to change this `var itemLink = $('.owl-item a');` to `var itemLink = $('.list-item a');`

Comment: Nope doesn't work. The function works as it is, but not on every instance of 'slider-mobile'